Visualzing the projective harmonic conjugate on a golden spiral
The Wikipedia article on the "Golden Spiral" states that:
With respect to logarithmic spirals the golden spiral has the distinguishing property that for four collinear spiral points A, B, C, D belonging to arguments θ, θ + π, θ + 2π, θ + 3π the point C is the projective harmonic conjugate of B with respect to A, D, i.e. the cross ratio (A,D;B,C) has the singular value −1. The golden spiral is the only logarithmic spiral with (A,D;B,C) = (A,D;C,B). (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20a%20golden%20spiral,every%20quarter%20turn%20it%20makes)
I'm trying to visualize what this is saying. I can't tell if by 'collinear' they mean on a new straight line out through the origin, cutting through the spiral at 4 points, and it's the straight-line ratios on that line that are harmonic. Or, if by 'collinear' they mean points on the spiral itself, and it's the curved distances between the points (curved portions of the spiral itself) that are harmonic.  Thanks

The condition on the arguments indicates that the common line is a ray eminating from the origin, and $A, B, C, D$ are four consecutive intersections of the ray with the spiral. The cross-ratios are of straight-line distances, not "along the spiral".

@PaulSinclair Thank you, so the condition on the argument you mention is that π=180 degrees correct?  So what they're describing is a polar coordinate graph with the normal conventions? I tried using Desmos' 'Polar graph' and it didn't come out right but I'm a novice so I probably made a mistake. Anyway, if one mapped the golden spiral on a sphere, it would be a loxodrome, and looking down from the perspective of the north/south pole, there would be the straight line ray from that pole to the equator, and then I'd see that ray intersecting that loxodrome harmonically, right? Thanks again

That $\pi$ radians $= 180$ degrees is just a fact provable from the definition of "radians" and "degrees", not a condition on the arguments. The condition on the arguments of the points $A,B,C,D$ is they increase by $\pi$ radians, so that each is halfway around from the other (i.e, lying on the same line through the origin, but on opposite sides). As for the rest of your comment, I am not clear on what you are describing, but it sounds like you are projecting the spiral onto the sphere, then asking if you projected it back into the plane by the inverse projection, would it change. No.
